# puppeteer waitForSelector and "none-existing" element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

If you try the following simple example, you will find it is working without a problem:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const response = await page.goto(`https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/TSLA`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  console.log(await response.text());

  let selector = `div#chart-toolbar ul > li`
  page.waitForSelector(selector)
  selector = `div#chart-toolbar ul > li:nth-child( 7 ) > button` // > span > span
  page.click(selector)

  const inputElement = await page.$('div#fin-chartiq')
  await inputElement.screenshot({path: 'yahoo-finance.png'})
  await browser.close();

})();
```

The `yahoo-finance.png` file looks like this:

[image]

However, if you take a closer look at the saved page source, you'd find that the keyword `chart-toolbar` is simply not in the file.

How come the above code can work, with such *"none-existing"* element?

The reason I'm asking is that, this is the stripped down version from my complicated **scraping** program, in which `puppeteer`, `browser`, `page`, and `selector` all comes from different level of class hierarchy, of which I'm getting:

`TimeoutError: waiting for selector "div#chart-toolbar ul > li" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded`

The code is literally the same, but just within different class files, I've run out of ideas why one works mystically, while the others doesn't. Please help. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a thing as "none-existing" element. The element is in the final DOM and `response.text()` only gives you the original HTML content. For the final DOM use `page.content()`:

```js
const response = await page.goto(`https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/TSLA`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
console.log(await page.content());
```

Regarding the timeout, it might be a race condition between navigation and waiting for the element to appear. This can happen for many reasons and it's very difficult to pinpoint the problem without looking at the code. I'd suggest to set headless to false, navigate to the page, and see if the navigation is complete and you can find the element you're looking for.

---

I also noted that you're not `await`ing `waitForSelector` and `click`. I'm getting expected results using the following:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    try{
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      //HERE change networkidle2 to networkidle0
      const response = await page.goto(`https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/TSLA`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

      let selector = `div#chart-toolbar ul > li`
      await page.waitForSelector(selector)
      selector = `div#chart-toolbar ul > li:nth-child( 7 ) > button` // > span > span
      await page.click(selector)


      const inputElement = await page.$('div#fin-chartiq')
      await inputElement.screenshot({path: 'yahoo-finance.png'})

    }catch(err) {console.log(err.message);}
    finally{
        await browser.close();
    }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mbit, allow me to ask one more question before accepting your answer -- for my complicated script, if I set headless to false, it will always find the element (but the following `page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0',})` will *always* timeout), whereas if I set headless back to true, it will *always* timeout, I try log `page.content()` before that, and indeed the keyword `chart-toolbar` is *not* in the output. 
I.e., it's the exact same code, only toggling headless setting will cause such huge difference. What else should I try, if I'm to troubleshoot it myself? THX!

Comment: ... if I set headless back to true, it will always timeout _trying to find the element as in OP_. I know it's hard to tell the problem without looking at the code, so if you don't have any more suggestions, I'm OK with it too. thx again.

Comment: @xpt I didn't understand the issue, in both cases you're getting timeout but in different places? where do you have `page.waitForNavigation()`? I tested the code with `page.content()` and w/o headless and in all cases I can see `chart-toolbar` in the dumped DOM.

Comment: page.waitForSelector > page.click then page.waitForNavigation to wait for screen to refresh in my code. But anyway, forget about page.waitForNavigation for now, and let's focus on `page.waitForSelector` -- with the same code, just toggling headless setting, one case is you can always find it, as you've seen, and one case is it'll *always* times out, and keyword `chart-toolbar` is not in the output of page.content(), as for my code. This is what I'm trying to understand. if you don't have any more suggestions, I'm OK with it too.

Comment: @xpt try setting the `waitUntil: ['load','domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']` in `page.goto` and/or putting a second delay with `page.waitFor()` before `page.content()`. if that gets the correct result in headless mode, it means it fetches the results prematurely before the page gets loaded.

Comment: @xpt for the `page.waitForNavigation()` problem: if you're sure that only click causes the navigation, wrap the clicking and then waiting in a `Promise.all`: `Promise.all([page.click(), page.waitForNavigation()])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206250/discussion-between-xpt-and-mbit).